# MySQL GROUP BY with GROUP_CONCAT return all row merged?

Tags: mysql

I ran into a problem today. I got a table with coins values :

```
0.01
0.01
0.01
0.05
0.10
0.25
1.00
1.00
2.00
and so on...
```

So the main idea is to get all the value one time so 0.01, 0.05, etc..

So I do :

```
SELECT Valeur FROM Mint_Coins GROUP BY Valeur
```

Now it will give me one row for each value... I want all values in one row so I use this :

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(',', Valeur) AS Values FROM Mint_Coins GROUP BY Valeur
```

It give me again 7 rows in blob... to have blob it mean that the row are over 512 bytes... Okay, let's see when I convert that they contain... results is now :

```
0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01
0.05, 0.05
etc..
```

So what I am doing wrong ? I want the result to hold in one colomn and one row like this `0.01,0.05,0.10,0.25,1.00,2.00`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass distinct to group_concat to ignore duplicated values:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Valeur) AS Values FROM Mint_Coins
```

You also don't need to group by in this case.

If you wanted the results in multiple rows, you could also have done:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Valeur FROM Mint_Coins
```

Comment: Res is : [BLOB - 34o]. Let me try to convert

Comment: `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CAST(Valeur AS CHAR(4))) FROM Mint_Coins`

This is working.... I think MySQL don't like to `group_concat` float values...

Comment: It works on my end with MySQL 5.5.13. Might be a bug in previous versions, or have something to do with the length of the field. Anyway, if your workaround works, great!

Comment: I did upgrade to 5.5.22. It's working without the casting ! Magic.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(A.Valuer SEPARATOR ',') AS Valuer
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Valuer FROM Mint_Coins)A ORDER BY Valuer;
```

Check this valuable link.This will help you.

http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a nested subquery?

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(',', (SELECT Valeur FROM Mint_Coins GROUP BY Valeur)) AS Values FROM Mint_Coins
```

Comment: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row